# Activate jquery calendar after date textbox written to html from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hi I am trying to reference the datepicker from my page after the textbox that selects the datepicker is written to the html document from javascript. Just wondering if there's some way to trigger this. Normally I would just have written  in line but for what I'm doing I need it to be dynamic.

```
        <body>
  <script>
  function popHTML() {
  var MyInside = document.getElementById("MyInside")
  var ohtml
  ohtml = ""

  ohtml = "<table><tr><td height=\"37\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"XDATE2\" name=\"XDATE2\" /></td></tr></table>"

  MyInside.innerHTML = ohtml
  }
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

  <table><tr><td><input type="button" onclick="popHTML()"></td><td id="MyInside"></td></tr></table>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  var DatePicked = function() { 

            var departure = $("#XDATE"); 
            var arrival = $("#arrival"); 
            var nights = $("#nights"); 

            var triggeringElement = $(this); 

            var departureDate = departure.datepicker("getDate"); 


    } 
    $(function() { 

            $("#XDATE, #arrival").datepicker({ 
                    onSelect: DatePicked 
            }); 

    }); 

</script>   






  </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this piece of code

```
$("#XDATE, #arrival").datepicker({ 
                    onSelect: DatePicked 
            });
```

Inside the function (or call from) inside the function that writes the input element to the document, and after the input element is written.

In your case will be after this line:

```
MyInside.innerHTML = ohtml
```